# Button_to pointed to a patch/update method doesn't works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What i'm trying to do is a button_to that point to the patch (update?) inside my controller, but it doesn't works. This is my code.

```
        <div>
    <%= product.picture? ? image_tag(product.picture_url, :alt => product.name) : image_tag("https://via.placeholder.com/250x250") %>
    Product: <%= product.name %><br />
    Description: <%= product.description %><br />
    Price: <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(product.price) %><br />
    Venduto da: <%= product.user.email %><br />
    <%= button_to "Remove", {controller: "orders", action: 'remove', :id => product.id}, :method=>:patch %>
    </div>
```

in the update method, assuming that i make it works sooner or later, i should insert a logic to remove a product from the order itself. At the moment if i go to the view page inside the index.html.erb which contains the list of the order to pay with inside the relative products added. The order in my case is a sort of cart. I get this error:

No route matches {:action=>"remove", :controller=>"orders", :id=>456}

these are my routes:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home'
  devise_for :users
  resources :products
  resources :orders, only: [:show, :create, :index, :destroy, :patch]

  require "sidekiq/web"
  authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin } do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end
end
```

as you can see i added the :patch route, but it still doesn't work.
I think the problem is in the first place inside my routes...
I have some questions now.
1: If i want to create a link_to or a button_to helper to execute a different method from the common crud operation, do i have to create a route to that custom method? Can you make an example in case?
2: In my case, am i doing a post, a get request or a patch? (i'm trying with patch, because i'm updating my order so i guess there is where i should insert the logic to remove the product inside the order) the documentation of rails is great but about the routing, I'm very confused at the moment as soon i want to do something out of the schemas i get stuck days trying to make it works.
3: Can someone link me to a good guide with examples to understand routing? Thank you.

UPDATE i found the solution:

```
<%= button_to("Remove", {:controller => "orders", :action => "update", :id => product.id}, :method => :patch) %>
```

and i added in the route this:

```
  patch '/orders', action: :update, controller: 'orders'
```

now it works but i still have doubts about why it is working :/

Comment: here is #3: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly : Change `action: 'remove'` to `action: 'destroy'`.

Most browsers only support *GET*, *POST*, *OPTION* but all the other methods are emulated by Rails using hidden form field *_method*.

When you say `method: 'patch'` it means that in `request.method` in you controller's method it will be `patch` but in if you want to specify the exact **method** in the controller you should use `action`

Hope that will help :)

Comment: So, should i remove the entire "action: remove"? I'm trying to trigger the update method only. <%= button_to "Remove", {controller: "orders", :id => product.id}, :method=>:patch %> if i use this code and click the button, it redirects me here http://localhost:3000/orders?id=456 and it gives me this error in the view No route matches [PATCH] "/orders"

Comment: As far as I remember, if you want to address `update` action, you can use `PUT`?

Comment: i updated my answer, yes i think i could use PUT as well in my route and in the button_to for the Update method. Thank you!